# Keep text in div

Tags: html

If I do:

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: yellow; font-size: xx-large;">
    Hello 1<br>
    Hello 2<br>
    Hello 3<br>
    Hello 4<br>
    Hello 5<br>
    Hello 6<br>
    Hello 7<be>
</div>
```

The text bleeds out of the DIV.  I want it to either cut the display of the text off or put scrollbars.  Anything but have the text just exit the DIV!  I understand that this is basically what the `<textarea>` does, but I'm trying not to use that tag for other reasons.

Sure appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage `overflow-y` to **force** a scrollbar on the *y-axis*.

Which produces:

```html
    <div style="overflow-y:auto;width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: yellow; font-size: xx-large;">
        Hello 1<br>
        Hello 2<br>
        Hello 3<br>
        Hello 4<br>
        Hello 5<br>
        Hello 6<br>
        Hello 7<be>
    </div>
```

If you want to cut out the redundant text, you can use `overflow:hidden` which hides text that exceeds the width and height.

```html
<div style="width: 200px; overflow:hidden;height: 200px; background-color: yellow; font-size: xx-large;">
        Hello 1<br>
        Hello 2<br>
        Hello 3<br>
        Hello 4<br>
        Hello 5<br>
        Hello 6<br>
        Hello 7<be>
    </div>
```

Comment: @BlakeMcBride Glad to help :p

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property

`overflow: hidden` will hide the text that is outside of the container with no scroll bar

`overflow: scroll` will always show a scrollbar

`overflow: auto` will automatically show a scrollbar if the text starts to go beyond the edge of the container

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: xx-large;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello 1<br>
  Hello 2<br>
  Hello 3<br>
  Hello 4<br>
  Hello 5<br>
  Hello 6<br>
  Hello 7<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width: 200px; height: 200px;` from style if you want to keep the field as big as the given text